# Object instantiation within destructor of same class and garbage collection

Tags: c#, c++, object, garbage-collection, instantiation

Recently, while taking an introductory unit focused on Object Oriented programming, I was introduced to the Garbage Collector in C#, and that it's role is to "clean up" objects that are no longer being referenced. Then I was introduced to destructors, and how they're called just before the object is deleted.

Naturally, I got thinking, but I never remembered to ask the lecturer about it; what will happen if you create an instance of a class within the destructor of the same class?

**C# example**

```
class Person{
 ~Person(){

  Person p = new Person();
  Console.WriteLine("Person destroyed");

 }
}

class Program{
 static void Main(string[] args){
  Person p = new Person();
 }
}
```

I would like to approach this from a more theoretical point of view, so I'm reluctant (at this stage) to try it since I probably wouldn't understand anyway, but I have a few theories. Besides, I'm not at my regular computer right now ;)

- Person.~Person() is going to recurse, as each time the new Person is created, it's going to call its destructor and create a new Person ad infinitum, or until some kind of memory-related exception occurs. Subsequently, main will never terminate.
- The compiler will complain (adding this option to every scenario seems like a good idea anyway).
- Somehow, some kind of "destructor skipping" will occur. ie. object destruction wouldn't be called sequentially, so neither would the constructor.

Now for a similarly related question. If the Garbage Collector's role is to delete the objects that are no longer referenced/needed, how would a situation like the one above be handled in an environment without a Garbage Collector - say, C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real mystery here I think.

It won't 'recurse' as such - you're just chucking a new object on the managed heap which is immediately dereferenced; thus making it a candidate for garbage collection.

Eventually the garbage collector will come round again, triggering the operation again etc.

That's not recursion - more like a chain.  But ultimately each `Person` will be removed from memory.

And, after a while the Garbage collector will send you an email complaining that you're not playing fair.

As for C++, well my guess is a stack overflow, since construction/destruction is happening there and then, and a very sulky computer afterwards.

If your next logical thought is 'shouldn't the runtime/language stop this from happening?' - no.  The language or runtimes in question are not there to stop you doing something that would otherwise be considered ill-advised; it trusts you, the programmer, to make sure you're not doing that.

That said - in an application shutdown scenario (re your comment below) the .Net runtime is going to act out of self-interest and will ultimately stop processing these finalizers to enact a shutdown.  Finalizers are for your benefit, not the runtime's.

Comment: I'm curious to know how does the execution of this simple program stop? It will evidently start chaining finalizers and outputting to the Console. How does the runtime actually kill this process (as normal termination does run finalizers as far as I know).

Comment: @InBetween - If it's an abnormal termination, there's no issue. In a co-operative shutdown, if the .Net runtime sees that the application is not playing ball it will ultimately stop processing finalizers and just release everything. Finalizers are as much a courtesy to your program than anything else. With the more modern Windows operating systems, once the process is shutdown, it's resources will be released as well.

Answer (score 2):

A more interesting point to make is that an object can actually [resurrect itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/04/13/object-resurrection-using-gc-reregisterforfinalize.aspx) in the finalizer!

```
class Foo
{
    static public List<Foo> ZombieFoos = new List<Foo>;

    ~Foo()
    {
        ZombieFoos.Add(this);

        // Now there is a reference to this instance again (in the list)..
        // The GC will not reclaim this instance.. huzzah we have been resurrected!!
    }
}
```

Not even remotely recommended...

Comment: awesome way to cause trouble!

Comment: I don't know of the C# case, but in Java this is dangerous and probably confusing, the object will be resurrected, but the properties of it will change. In particular, the finalizer is only called once on each object, which means that the object will come back once, but it will not repeatedly do so, which might be surprising (well, as surprising as the object coming back from the land of the dead in the first place...). You can read this article for the Java case [Object Finalization and cleanup](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-1998/jw-06-techniques.html)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas the same is true in C#, you would have to manually re-register the object for finalization. But as with Java, this is dangerous and *definitely* confusing in C# too, I only mention it becuase, well, it's zombie objects! Or a Jesus class, whatever you want to call it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could, in fact, cause system to be 99.9 time in GC. Just acquire sufficient amount of memory by every Person object for GC to trigger Heap 0 collection.